# Is any checkbox checked with ID matching pattern before and after

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I have a form with checkboxes. The relevant checkboxes have ID attribute starting with pattern `stop_` and ending with an underscore and number.

so it might be for example

```
stop_bla_4
stop_blu_4
```

but not

```
stop_bla_5
stop_blz_5
```

How would I test if none of the checkboxes in a group are checked.

i.e. those that start with `stop_` and end with `_4` in the above example while ignoring the others.

Comment: @ArunPJohny his IDs ARE unique though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should help you:

```
// None checked
$('input[type="checkbox"][id^="stop_"][id$="_4"]:checked').length == 0
```

**jQuery references**

Selector "attribute starts with": http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/

Selector "attribute ends with": http://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/

Comment: how does this work if some are unchecked and some are checked? why does it show only if all or unchecked?

Comment: I used `length` because you asked about the unchecked ones (number of checked == 0), but based on the selector you can achieve any situation.